# How to set date in mysql to null and not to 0000-00-00

Tags: php, mysql

[image]I just finished a login-system and added another table for the useres personal information. For this reason, I have som inputs which aren't required. Textfields are nor problem but there is a problem with date and numberfields:
Since the User isn't forced to give all the information fields that aren't filledin should be NULL. But in case of date it alway gives me 0000-00-00 instead and in case of number its always 0.

I give you the whole code because I#m not sure about what is most important but I think its line 9, 10, 14-21, 73, 76

```
<?php

  $user_id = $_GET['id'];

  if(isset($_POST['add-personal-data'])){
    $geschlecht = $_POST['geschlecht'];
    $vorname = $_POST['vorname'];
    $nachname = $_POST['nachname'];
    $alter = $_POST['alter'];
    $input_date = $_POST['geburtsdatum'];
    $lieblingsziel = $_POST['lieblingsziel'];
    $beschreibung = $_POST['beschreibung'];

    if($input_date != null){
      $geburtsdatum = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($input_date));
    } else {
      $geburtsdatum = NULL;
    }

    $beschreibung_statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO beschreibung (user_id, name, vorname, geschlecht, user_alter, geburtsdatum, lieblingsziel, beschreibung)
                                            VALUES ('$user_id', '$nachname', '$vorname', '$geschlecht', '$alter', '$geburtsdatum', '$lieblingsziel', '$beschreibung')");

    $user_control_statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id = '$user_id'");
    $user_control_statement->execute();
    $user = $user_control_statement->fetch();

    if($user != NULL){

        $user_has_description_statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM beschreibung WHERE user_id = '$user_id'");
        $user_has_description_statement->execute();
        $description = $user_has_description_statement->fetch();

        if($description == NULL){
          $beschreibung_statement->execute();
        } else {
          echo ('<div class="line fehler"><p> Dieser Benutzer besitzt bereits eine Beschreibung. </p></div>');
        }

    } else {
      echo ('<div class="line fehler"><p> Dieser Benutzer existiert nicht. </p></div>');
    }
  }

    echo $geschlecht . "<br>" . $vorname . "<br>" . $nachname . "<br>" . $alter . "<br>" . $geburtsdatum . "<br>" . $lieblingsziel . "<br>" . $beschreibung ;

?>
<main>
  <div class="line">

    <div class="register">

      <form method="post" action="?p=add-personal-data&id=<?php echo $user_id; ?>">

        <h2>Persönliche Daten</h2>
        <hr />
        <p>Daten, die du hier angibst, werden auf deinem Profil angezeigt.</p>

        <h4>Geschlecht</h4>
        <select name="geschlecht" class="datafield">
          <option>männlich</option>
          <option>weiblich</option>
          <option>anderes</option>
          <option selected>keine Angabe</option>
        </select>

        <h4>Vorname</h4>
        <input type="text" name="vorname" placeholder="Vorname" class="datafield" value="">

        <h4>Nachname</h4>
        <input type="text" name="nachname" placeholder="Nachname" class="datafield" value="">

        <h4>Alter</h4>
        <input type="number" name="alter" placeholder="Alter" class="datafield" value="">

        <h4>Geburtsdatum</h4>
        <input type="date" name="geburtsdatum" placeholder="Geburtsdatum" class="datafield" value="">

        <h4>Lieblingsziel</h4>
        <input type="text" name="lieblingsziel" placeholder="Lieblingsziel" class="datafield" value="">

        <h4>Beschreibung</h4>
        <textarea name="beschreibung" wrap="soft" class="datafield" rows="5" placeholder="Gib hier persönliche information, wie zum Beispiel Hobbies an."></textarea>

        <div>
          <input type="submit" name="add-personal-data" value="Speichern" class="submitbutton">
        </div>

      </form>
    </div>

  </div>
</main>
```

How can I set NULL to "geburtsdatum" and "user_alter" if the user doesn't give any information?

Comment: Set `DEFAULT NULL` and then insert *`NULL`*

Comment: To elaborate on what @ZainFarooq mean, is you have to change that column's property to `DEFAULT NULL` and then put your value as null

Comment: @window.document Yes but we can also assign `NULL` without setting default to null but if you don't be even allowed to enter null value then you have to set allow null

Comment: If the data type is set to date then it will never take NULL as a value. If you want date as null then change datatype to varchar. And while reading date from database, you should type cast the VARCHAR to DATE

Comment: It's good that you use PDO, but you should use placeholders in your query instead of interpolating the values. Otherwise you are still vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 2):

Set default value to `NULL` or you can simply insert `NULL` value if the user doesn't give any information. Plus if you set *`DEFAULT`* to *`NULL`* then you don't even need to assign it any value. It will automatically assign it *`NULL`*

You can add you insert query for *`NULL`* simply like this

```
INSERT INTO beschreibung (geburtsdatum, user_alter, ...) VALUES (NULL,NULL,...);
```

Still, if you face problems then you need to go to phpmyadmin and make it allow null by checking this checkbox 
[image]

**Update**
As Mangesh Sathe defined in the comment section you need to change the type to *`DATETIME`* or *`TIMESTAMP`* instead of `date`

Comment: I have this hook but it still doesn't work. INSERT INTO beschreibung (geburtsdatum, user_alter, ...) VALUES (NULL,NULL,...);  isn't possible aswell because then there is nothing inserted if the user types something in.

Comment: As Mangesh defined you have to change the *`Type`* to `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` instead of *`date`*

Answer (score 0):

First of all set the default value of geburtsdatum column `NULL` in your database. Now I think it would be better if you use 2 query strings or both if and else for geburtsdatum. If date is null, then do not insert it in the query.

Like:

```
$insert_query = '';
if($input_date != null){
  $geburtsdatum = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($input_date));
  $insert_query = "INSERT INTO beschreibung (user_id, name, vorname, geschlecht, user_alter, geburtsdatum, lieblingsziel, beschreibung)
                                        VALUES ('$user_id', '$nachname', '$vorname', '$geschlecht', '$alter', '$geburtsdatum', '$lieblingsziel', '$beschreibung')";
} else {
  // there is no geburtsdatum in the query.
  $insert_query = "INSERT INTO beschreibung (user_id, name, vorname, geschlecht, user_alter, lieblingsziel, beschreibung)
                                        VALUES ('$user_id', '$nachname', '$vorname', '$geschlecht', '$alter', '$lieblingsziel', '$beschreibung')"
}
$beschreibung_statement = $pdo->prepare($insert_query);
```

[image]

Comment: Thats the only solution for date type column

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution outside prepare:

You set either `$geburtsdatum` to string `NULL`, or to the quoted (not only escaped) date.

```
if( $input_date != null ){
    $geburtsdatum = '"'.date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($input_date)).'"';
} else {
    $geburtsdatum = "NULL";
}
```

Then in the VALUES() part you write it without quotes:

```
VALUES ( ..., '$alter', $geburtsdatum, '$lieblingsziel', ... )
```

Answer (score 0):

If your geburtsdatum column already set to accept NULL values and Default set to NULL, you should instead separate the db statement into 2.

```
$geburtsdatum = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($input_date));

if($input_date != null){
  $beschreibung_statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO beschreibung (user_id, name, vorname, geschlecht, user_alter, geburtsdatum, lieblingsziel, beschreibung)
                                        VALUES ('$user_id', '$nachname', '$vorname', '$geschlecht', '$alter', '$geburtsdatum', '$lieblingsziel', '$beschreibung')");

} else {
  //this statement will assign NULL into geburtsdatum field
  $beschreibung_statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO beschreibung (user_id, name, vorname, geschlecht, user_alter, lieblingsziel, beschreibung)
                                        VALUES ('$user_id', '$nachname', '$vorname', '$geschlecht', '$alter', '$lieblingsziel', '$beschreibung')");
}
```